# PHP use variable from global space inside class

Tags: php, class, scope

Hi I'm writing some code in PHP. I need to use a variable from the global scope inside my class but it doesn't work. I don't know if I need to use namespace or not and how ? Thank you
Sample :

```
<?PHP

$plantask_global_script = array("one", "two");
$plantask_global_config = array("three", "four");
$myvar = array_merge($plantask_global_script, $plantask_global_config);

class Env implements ArrayAccess
{
    static private $container = $myvar;

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            self::$container[] = $value;
        } else {
            self::$container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset(self::$container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset(self::$container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return isset(self::$container[$offset]) ? self::$container[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding in the first line of your class the code: global $myvar;

Comment: By the way, global variables in general are not good OOP practice, they create tight coupling of your class to the global variable

Comment: To avoid the $GLOBALS you can create a getter and a setter method to use that value inside the class.

Comment: I recomment that you remove the `[answered]` from the title. We can easily see if a question has answers and if an answer was the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `$myvar` as a superglobal:

```
private static $container = $GLOBALS['myvar'];
```

Although, as Ron Dadon pointed out, this is generally bad practice in OOP.

**EDIT:**

I jumped the gun here. My above solution *does not actually work*, at least not for me. So, a better way to achieve this would be the following:

```
$myvar = array_merge($plantask_global_script, $plantask_global_config);

class Env implements ArrayAccess
{
    private static $container = null;

    public static function init($var)
    {
        self::$container = $var;
    }

    ...
}

Env::init($myvar);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can close now. :)

Comment: Please see my edit. I believe my original suggestion does not actually work. I want to make sure your question is properly answered :)